# How to make two fields as one primary key in ormlite?

Tags: android, sql, orm, sqlite, ormlite

create table temp(id int,userId int,query text,createdOn text,primary key(id,userId));

How can I create id and UserId as one primary key using ormlite ?

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "_id",id = true,generatedId = true)
private long _id;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "userId")
private String userId;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "query")
public String query;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "createdOn")
public String createdOn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "_id",id = true,generatedId = true)
private long _id;
```

_id it is primary key when you used generatedId = true;

Comment: but i want _id and userId combined to be the primary key